# Error on blur for Select MUI DataGridPro / DataGridPremium in renderHeader

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

The `onBlur` event on the `<Select />` component is triggering this error when rendered in a column header of a `<DataGridPro />` or `<DataGridPremium />`:

```
Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

```
return (
  ...
  <DataGridPro
    ...
    columns={[
      ...
      renderHeader: () => (
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>Choose Me</InputLabel>
          <Select
              label="Choose Me"
              size="small"
              onChange={setItem}
            >
            <MenuItem value="Option 1">Option 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Option 2">Option 2</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      ),
    ]}
  />
  ...
);
```

If you try changing the value, it works. But when the focus leaves the `<Select />` it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the MUI team has come out with a solution for it:
https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3393

If the out-of-the-box solution does not work for you, the error will cab be prevented if the `onBlur` is prevented from bubbling up.

https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3393#issuecomment-1111872757

```
return (
  ...
  <DataGridPro
    ...
    columns={[
      ...
      renderHeader: () => (
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>Choose Me</InputLabel>
          <Select
              onBlur={e => e.stopPropagation()} // <-- THIS
              label="Choose Me"
              size="small"
              onChange={setItem}
            >
            <MenuItem value="Option 1">Option 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Option 2">Option 2</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      ),
    ]}
  />
  ...
);
```